# RedshiftML - Retraining Models

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-redshift

Does anyone have experience using redshiftML and have guidance on updating models? I had our BI team enable this feature in redshift, but our organization has no experience with this tool. I end up with all types of errors when trying to update models and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction

When dropping a model, I get the error below. Is this a permissions issue?
`[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: cache lookup failed for function 149004315` 
When retraining a model, I get the error below. Is there guidance on replacing/retraining models?
`[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function "model_name" already exists with same argument types`

There isn't a lot of documentation, so I initially started out with these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_MODEL.html

If I can't get past the errors of dropping a model, then I think I'll end up having to set up daily model versioning and bloating the database
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implement-model-versioning-with-amazon-redshift-ml/